# How do I set Command-Tab as the trigger for Witch?

Tags: application-switcher

I'm using the app switcher, [Witch](https://manytricks.com/witch/), and I can't figure out how to set it to activate on Command-Tab. When I try to capture the keys, the OS switches apps on me. I can set Witch to activate on Option-Tab without issue.

Answer (score 7):

I'm adding this because it took me a couple  weeks to find it:

Instead of trying to capture the key combination for Command-Tab, click the gear icons next to the Keyboard fields on the Witch preferences pane. It will give you options for setting the trigger to Command-Tab or Command-Shift-Tab.

[image]

Comment: Since the time of posting, the gear icon has bee replaced by a circle with three dots

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for posting this.